# Jquery Validation on the Basis of Class Name

Tags: jquery, validation

HTML Page

```html
<input id="Text1" type="text" class="abc" /><input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit1" />
    <input id="Text2" type="text" class="abc2" /><input id="Submit2" type="submit" value="submit2" />
```

```js
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Submit1").on("click", test1);
            $("#Submit2").on("click", test2);
        });
        function grRules(className) {
            removeAllRules();

            $("#form1").validate();
            $("." + className).rules("add", { required: true, messages: { required: ""} });

            if ($("#form1").valid())
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        function test1() {
            if (grRules("abc"))
                alert("ok! fine");
        }

        function test2() {
            if (grRules("abc2"))
                alert("ok! fine");
        }


function removeAllRules() {
    $('#form1').removeData('validator');
}
```

On Button Clicking I m passing Class Name which will be going to validate .. and every time button will be clicked .. then all previous validation will be removed

let say both InputField's are Empty .. I clicked on "Button1" form will not submit b/c "Text1" is Empty .. now I will Fill up "Text2" and clicked on "Button2" ..here form Should have to submit .. but shoehow it stuck and displaying error validation Error

please check what i m doing wrong

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution : I was Missing **Name Attribute** in Input Fields that's why validation Was not working

Any ways thanks :)